# How to disable the "Refreshing SDK" when I create a project onStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

In Android Studio, when I click the "Start a new Android Studio project" on the main window;
and then, a dialog pop up, this is the picture of the dialog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oEjd.jpg

It take some time to download something, look like a part of SDK, but my SDK is downloaded already;
the "Support Repository" is already downloaded too;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pklh.png

I hate this time to wait, and I want to disable this function or something, so I searching for the answer about this question, but nothing found;

I have some not too good ideas for this, one is disable the "Android Repository" on "SDK Update Sites" of "SDK Manager", if I do this, the Download Dialog shown still, but it can't download anything, so the wait time became shorter, but I can't stand too.

My version of Android Studio is 2.3.1;

Answer (score 0):

you can simply disable your network when you want to open or start a project or you can give the android studio a fake proxy to disable its access to google repositories (i never test the second one but it may work ).
truly you can't get rid of these downloads in the android studio and it's a tab-suffering search.
another bothering issue which may also happen for you is that your android studio download or update gradle and it takes so much time.
for this issue, you can go to setting-> build, execution ... -> build tools -> gradle, then mark the offline work.this is a default setting for all projects.
if you already opened a project you can also select a local gradle folder for this project there.